# Generating values to a column until next value arrives in a hive table

Tags: pyspark, hive

I have two datasets as below

1. dataset1

```
cust_id     pt_dt
985XFT82Y4  20200824
985XFT82Y4  20200826
985XFT82Y4  20200902
985XFT82Y4  20200918
985XFT82Y4  20200930
985XFT82Y4  20201016
985XFT82Y4  20201021
985XFT82Y4  20201102
985XFT82Y4  20201111
985XFT82Y4  20201112
985XFT82Y4  20201208
985XFT82Y4  20210111
985XFT82Y4  20210202
985XFT82Y4  20210303
985XFT82Y4  20210309
985XFT82Y4  20210311
```

Another,
2. dataset2

```
cust_id     chg_date                       ins_status
985XFT82Y4  2020-08-24 22:12:34.332000     subscribed
985XFT82Y4  2020-11-11 14:45:31.152000     installed
985XFT82Y4  2021-02-02 01:26:34.500000     migration
985XFT82Y4  2021-03-09 08:11:57.790000     setup done
```

No I need to join these two datasets and produce a data set **datset_result** which should have the fields cust_id, pt_dt, ins_status
The join should be done on cust_id and pt_dt/chg_date. The result should be something like below.

```
cust_id     pt_dt           ins_status
985XFT82Y4  20200824        subscribed
985XFT82Y4  20200826        subscribed
985XFT82Y4  20200902        subscribed
985XFT82Y4  20200918        subscribed
985XFT82Y4  20200930        subscribed
985XFT82Y4  20201016        subscribed
985XFT82Y4  20201021        subscribed
985XFT82Y4  20201102        subscribed
985XFT82Y4  20201111        installed
985XFT82Y4  20201112        installed
985XFT82Y4  20201208        installed
985XFT82Y4  20210111        installed
985XFT82Y4  20210202        migration
985XFT82Y4  20210303        migration
985XFT82Y4  20210309        setup done
985XFT82Y4  20210311        setup done
```

I have tried joining these two datasets as below but couldn't achieve it.

```
select a.cust_id, a.pt_dt, b.ins_status
from dataset1 a 
left join dataset2 b
on (a.cust_id = b.cust_id)
and (a.pt_dt = regexp_replace(substr(b.chg_date,1,10), '-', ''))
```

Can someone suggest me best way to do it in pyspark or hive.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps as follows:

- `string ---> timestamp ---> to_date`
- apply lead() function over window spec grouped over IDs, ordered by date
- What to do with "None" values in the first and last rows? fill them  with today's date then perform join and select relevant columns from each data frame.

Online code @ https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/8963851468310921/415303719801042/5846184720595634/latest.html

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
from datetime import datetime

data = [("985XFT82Y4", "20200824"),
("985XFT82Y4", "20200826"), 
("985XFT82Y4", "20200902"), 
("985XFT82Y4", "20200918"), 
("985XFT82Y4", "20200930"), 
("985XFT82Y4", "20201016"), 
("985XFT82Y4", "20201021"), 
("985XFT82Y4", "20201102"), 
("985XFT82Y4", "20201111"), 
("985XFT82Y4", "20201112"), 
("985XFT82Y4", "20201208"), 
("985XFT82Y4", "20210111"), 
("985XFT82Y4", "20210202"), 
("985XFT82Y4", "20210303"), 
("985XFT82Y4", "20210309"), 
("985XFT82Y4", "20210311")] 

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["cust_id", "pt_dt"]).withColumn("pt_dt", F.to_timestamp("pt_dt", "yyyyMMdd")).withColumn("pt_dt", F.date_format(F.col('pt_dt'),"yyyy-MM-dd"))
df1.show()

data1 = [("985XFT82Y4", "2020-08-24 22:12:34.332000",  "subscribed"),   
("985XFT82Y4", "2020-11-11 14:45:31.152000",  "installed"),     
("985XFT82Y4", "2021-02-02 01:26:34.500000",  "migration"),     
("985XFT82Y4", "2021-03-09 08:11:57.790000",  "setup done")]    
ts_pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, ["cust_id", "chg_date", "ins_status"]).withColumn("chg_date", F.to_timestamp("chg_date", ts_pattern)).withColumn("chg_date", F.date_format(F.col('chg_date'),"yyyy-MM-dd"))
df2.show()

window_spec = Window.partitionBy("cust_id").orderBy("chg_date")
df2 = df2.withColumn("end_chg_date", F.lead("chg_date").over(window_spec))
df2 = df2.withColumn("end_chg_date", F.when(F.col("end_chg_date").isNull(), F.lit(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))).otherwise(F.col("end_chg_date")))
df2.show()

+----------+----------+----------+------------+
|   cust_id|  chg_date|ins_status|end_chg_date|
+----------+----------+----------+------------+
|985XFT82Y4|2020-08-24|subscribed|  2021-03-16|
|985XFT82Y4|2020-11-11| installed|  2021-02-02|
|985XFT82Y4|2021-02-02| migration|  2021-03-09|
|985XFT82Y4|2021-03-09|setup done|  2021-03-16|
+----------+----------+----------+------------+

cond = [df1["cust_id"] == df2["cust_id"], df1["pt_dt"] >= df2["chg_date"], df1["pt_dt"] < df2["end_chg_date"]]
df3 = df1.join(df2, cond, "left").select(df1["cust_id"], df1["pt_dt"], "ins_status").orderBy("pt_dt")
# use df1 in select to resolve same column name conflict
df3.show()


+----------+----------+----------+
|   cust_id|     pt_dt|ins_status|
+----------+----------+----------+
|985XFT82Y4|2020-08-24|subscribed|
|985XFT82Y4|2020-08-26|subscribed|
|985XFT82Y4|2020-09-02|subscribed|
|985XFT82Y4|2020-09-18|subscribed|
|985XFT82Y4|2020-09-30|subscribed|
|985XFT82Y4|2020-10-16|subscribed|
|985XFT82Y4|2020-10-21|subscribed|
|985XFT82Y4|2020-11-02|subscribed|
|985XFT82Y4|2020-11-11| installed|
|985XFT82Y4|2020-11-12| installed|
|985XFT82Y4|2020-12-08| installed|
|985XFT82Y4|2021-01-11| installed|
|985XFT82Y4|2021-02-02| migration|
|985XFT82Y4|2021-03-03| migration|
|985XFT82Y4|2021-03-09|setup done|
|985XFT82Y4|2021-03-11|setup done|
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Hi @Mageswaran - Thanks for the response.
If you see the result obtained from your code, there's cross join happening. Where as the expected output should contain the `ins_status ` as  `subscribed ` from the chg_dt `2020-08-24`  to chg_dt `2020-11-11` and from `2020-11-11` to `2021-02-02` it should be `installed` and from `20210202` until `2021-03-09` it should be `migration` and so on....

Comment: Interesting! got it...let me try it out

Comment: is it possible to have start and end range for each of the `chg_date` ? that way we can use range joins Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/join-performance/range-join

Comment: can you check the notebook ? I came up with following logic, which may not suit your business requirements:  
- Forward fill the date for each `cust_id` and create a new date column, that act as end date
- For null rows in new column, fill with current date 
- Use multiple join conditions: id, start_date > value < end_date

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column with the date from the next row in `df2` (using `lead`) to facilitate range-based joining:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df3 = df1.withColumn('pt_date', F.to_date(df1.pt_dt.cast('string'), 'yyyyMMdd'))
df4 = df2.withColumn('next_date', F.lead('chg_date').over(Window.partitionBy('cust_id').orderBy('chg_date')))

result = df3.join(df4, 
    (df3.cust_id == df4.cust_id) & 
    (df3.pt_date >= df4.chg_date) & 
    ((df3.pt_date < df4.next_date) | df4.next_date.isNull()), 
    'left'
).select(df3.cust_id, df3.pt_dt, df4.ins_status)

result.show()
+----------+--------+----------+
|   cust_id|   pt_dt|ins_status|
+----------+--------+----------+
|985XFT82Y4|20200824|subscribed|
|985XFT82Y4|20200826|subscribed|
|985XFT82Y4|20200902|subscribed|
|985XFT82Y4|20200918|subscribed|
|985XFT82Y4|20200930|subscribed|
|985XFT82Y4|20201016|subscribed|
|985XFT82Y4|20201021|subscribed|
|985XFT82Y4|20201102|subscribed|
|985XFT82Y4|20201111| installed|
|985XFT82Y4|20201112| installed|
|985XFT82Y4|20201208| installed|
|985XFT82Y4|20210111| installed|
|985XFT82Y4|20210202| migration|
|985XFT82Y4|20210303| migration|
|985XFT82Y4|20210309|setup done|
|985XFT82Y4|20210311|setup done|
+----------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: Cool!  the condition `df4.next_date.isNull()` didn't cross my mind, I was doing extra work here...my bad!